# Smallest circle that encircles $n$ unit circles

Tags: geometry

For $n\in \Bbb{Z}^+$, let $r_\circ(n)$ be the smallest radius such that $n$ non-overlapping unit circles (of radius $1$) can fit into a circle of radius $r_\circ(n)$.

For example, $r_\circ(1)=1$,   $r_\circ(2)=2$,  and  $r_\circ(7)=3$.  It is fairly easy to calculate, with proofs, $r_\circ(n)$ for $<8$, and to prove that $r_\circ(n)$ is a non-decreasing function of $n$.  But there may be some values of $n$ such that $r_\circ(n)=r_\circ(n-1)$.

For example, it is quite plausible that the packing for $n=19$ is so efficient that you cannot construct a smaller enclosing circle even for $n=18$.  Call such values of $n$ "super-efficient circle packing numbers."

Is the distribution of super-efficient circle packing  numbers known?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: Or http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/

Comment: So, Mark, have you had a look at those references?

Comment: Yes, and they answer my curiousity

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write up and post an answer, incorporating what you've learned from those references